# How to display more information in the stage pipeline view?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to display certain environment variables and build parameters right into each stage's box? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use with Jenkins Scripted Pipeline only, here is example:

```
node {
    //create 3 stages
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        stage("Stage ${i}") {
            echo "do in stage ${i}"
        }
    }
    stage("Stage ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}") {
        echo "do something"
    }
    stage("Stage ${currentBuild.startTimeInMillis}") {
        echo "do something"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you call the stage is what's going to show up, and you can use variables if you wish. In this case, "node_to_run_on" is a build parameter.

```
node ("${node_to_run_on}") {
   stage("Install JDK / JRE on ${node_to_run_on}") {
      sh ("/blah/blah")
   }
}
```

Comment: but it's only for scripted pipeline